Recharts - Custom X axis tick - wrong transform on mobile screen
I am trying to have custom labels for my x axis ticks. It seems to work fine on web browsers, but I can't get it to position correctly on mobile when I rotate the icon.
This is my label code:
const CustomXAxisTick = ({ x, y, payload, data }: any) => {
        const degrees = 90 // this is dynamic later
        return (
            <g transform={`translate(${x},${y})`}>
                <foreignObject x={-6} y={14} dy={20} width={20} height={20}>
                    <FaArrowUp className="w-3 h-3" style={{ transform: `rotate(${degrees}deg)` }} />
                </foreignObject>
            </g>
        )
    }

On web:

However on mobile (see that the icon moved to the top left)

Any suggestions on how to fix that or why this is happening?

It looks like x and y are not coming through and your label is being rendered in the top left because of your x={-6} y={14} on the foreignObject. Guard against not having x or y values sent and that should get rid of having phantom labels.

On to why your labels aren't rendering in the right place.
Recharts tries to only show the labels that fit in the space provided. When there is less left in the SVG it will hide them. If they are rendering outside of the SVG you won't be able to see them anyways, so that is pre-calculated and hidden. There is also a chance that your set width is too large/static and that is causing the overlap to happen. You'll have to scale down your custom label until it fits.
First things I would do would be trying to set interval={0} on your XAxis and increasing margin on the bottom.
